# Fetching a value in a TextBox from a Table in MS Access Form

Tags: ms-access

I am working with a small Project in MS Access. I have created the database, forms.
I have a table Employee. There are fields EmployeeID and Employee Name.
In a random  Form, If I enter EmployeeID in textbox. It should automatically fetch Employee Name in other provided Textbox. Also it must Employee Name must change if I change EmployeeID. Please Help.

Comment: Use `DLookup()` function. Or use Textbox afterupdate event to filter form data. Read [DoCmd.ApplyFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.applyfilter) method article on microsoft.

Comment: Tried DLookup(). But its returning only the first value in the table.

Comment: Try `DLookup("[EmployeeID]","[Employee]","[EmployeeID]='" & TextBox1 & "'"` where textbox1 is your Employee ID textbox on form.

Comment: This would be if EmployeeID is string. My EmployeeID is of type number. I tried DLookup("[EmployeeID]","[Employee]","[EmployeeID]= [TextBox1] "). Still giving first value.

Comment: Then it would be `DLookup("[EmployeeID]","[Employee]","[EmployeeID]=" & [TextBox1] )`

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. I was trying that from last two days. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad to know it helped. Its my pleasure.